# Oracle 11g - What would be the equivalent to ordsys.timeseries from Oracle 8?

Tags: oracle, time-series

I am looking at as fast times series implementation as possible and in version 8, there used to be a ordsys.timeseries package, see http://www.iselfschooling.com/Free_Oracle_Training/04_Advanced/03_Articles_3/03_Articles_2/lesson32.html or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/cartridg.805/a57501/ts_tsuse.htm.

What would be the equivalent in Oracle 11g, pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, Oracle 8.1.5 was the last version where this cartrige was available. Now, the date and time handling in the database has been augmented by the use of analytic functions like `lead()` and `lag()` and so on. What used to be an additional option using funky Java stored procedures is now incorporated directly into the database engine. Use your regular SQL syntax and things should be just fine.